# Why ForeignKeyId is not filled automatically in Entity Framework?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, entity-framework-6

Consider following model:

```
public class Car
{
    public virtual Company Company { get; set; }
    public virtual string CompanyId { get; set; }
}
```

As I know `Company` and `CompanyId` should be synced by convention. So setting `Company` property should lead to setting `CompanyId` automatically. So the following test should pass:

```
myCar.Company = new Company() { Id = "11" };
Assert.AreEqual("11", myCar.CompanyId);
```

Why is that so?

My DbContext config is:

```
Configuration.LazyLoadingEnabled = false;
Configuration.ProxyCreationEnabled = false;
```

Comment: I don't think properties linked this way will update until you call `SaveChanges` on the context.

Comment: @BradleyUffner yep you're right. After Saving the data it's filled. Is there any way to have it set before saving changes. Or I should manually set the `CompanyId` in the setter of `Car.Company`?

Comment: Your unit test should not expect `CompanyId` to be populated until after `SaveChanges()` is called, as others have indicated.

Comment: @BradleyUffner I think your comment worth as answer!

Comment: I added an answer with a few extra notes for you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When using `POCOs` (Plain Old Class Objects) with entity framework, "linked" properties like you describe will only update each other when `SaveChanges` is called on the `DbContext` they are attached to.  As you can see in your class definition there is actually no "physical" connection between the properties, so updating one will not update the other directly.

The link is actually maintained by your dbContext, and is only updated once changes are saved to the database.  Even then it technically isn't updating the link, but doing a complete refresh of the object from the database.

As an extra note, .SaveChanges is very aptly named.  It actually stores the original values of the properties when loaded from the db and compares them, property by property, looking for changed values so that It knows what to update.  This can be VERY CPU and memory intensive.  If you are just reading data and know that you will never update the instances you should add [.AsNoTracking()](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/Gg679352(v=VS.103).aspx) to your linq query to make it no do all that.

Answer (score 2):

If you just new up an object and add it to an entity, that doesn't mean EF has registered that object and does a fetch from the database. You would need to hit the `DbContext` in order to do that. You can verify this by using whatever sql profiling tool you have available.

Comment: What do you mean by hitting the database?

Comment: The kind of operation you're doing would require EF to hit the database and match up the id values between `Company`'s `Id` and `Car`'s `CompanyId`. Because that round trip never happens and EF has no hands in the operation, they're never synced.

Comment: The `Id` is not generated in database. I assign a Guid to the Id in the constructor.

Comment: That doesn't matter. EF doesn't see it as one of the objects it's tracking so it will ignore what you do with it. You could try manually registering the newed up `Company` and then assigning it to your EF-tracked entity and see if things are updated then.

Answer (score 0):

Remove the virtual from CompanyId.

```
public class Car
{
    public virtual Company Company { get; set; }
    public string CompanyId { get; set; }
}
```

Edit: Bradley is right, you have to save the changes to view the linked property.
If you want to access the id before saving you can do this;

```
var comp = new Company { Id = "11" };
ctx.Companies.Add(comp);

var car = new Car {
    Id = "2",
    CompanyId = comp.Id 
};
ctx.Cars.Add(car);
```

Remember that doing it this way you must add both **comp** and **car** to the context.
The linked property **car.Company** will be null.

Comment: I tested it. didn't work! Also I've added my DbContext config to the question.